# How to convert an Excel date stored as nvarchar in SQL?

Tags: sql, excel, date, type-conversion

I used a dataflow task to insert Excel data into SQL, however it made a date field from excel into a nvarchar field in SQL.

I've made a lot of changes to the DB. And can't just truncate and reload the data at this point.

For instance, 4/19/2013 in excel turned into 41383 in SQL.

Is it possible to convert this into a date at this point?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (MySQL, SQL Server, etc.) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numeric representation of `4/19/2013` is `41383` in Excel, which is the number of *days* since roughly January 1, 1901.  So, you can try adding this numeric value from Excel as days to `1899-12-30` to get your desired date.

**SQL Server:**

```
DATEADD(d, 41383, '1899-12-30')
```

**MySQL:**

```
DATE_ADD('1899-12-30', INTERVAL 41383 DAY)
```

Sidenote: The reason why we are using `1899-12-30` as the starting point rather than `1900-01-01` has to do with a bug in Excel (not in SQL).

Comment: Interesting note about the bug in Excel +1

Comment: Should it really be considered a bug when its introduction was deliberate?

Comment: @user3486773 Happy to help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server:

```
Declare @N int = 42515

Select DateAdd(DAY,@N,'1899-12-30')
```

Returns  5/25/2016